# Why my array data does not print in render function REACTJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am stuck in reactjs.
I have a function in which there is an array containing some values, but when I want to access that array in render function and pass it using props to another function, it returns a blank array.
what should I do to resolve this problem?

Like this:

- In Function:
  `this.usersAnswerXML = ["ID0", "ID1", "ID2"]`
- In Render:
  `this.usersAnswerXML = []`

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
handleSplitContentClick(contentId, selectionType) {
  let isCorrect

  if (selectionType == 'selected') {
    const index = this.correctAnswers.indexOf(contentId);

    if (index > -1) {
      this.userCorrectAnswers.push(contentId);

      if (this.correctAnswers.length === this.userCorrectAnswers.length &&
          this.userUncorrectAnswer.length == 0) {

        isCorrect = this.correct

      } else {
        isCorrect = this.incorrect        
      }

    } else {
      this.userUncorrectAnswer.push(contentId);
      isCorrect = this.incorrect       
    }

  } else if (selectionType == 'disselected') {
    const index = this.correctAnswers.indexOf(contentId);

    if (index > -1) {
      this.userCorrectAnswers.splice(index, 1);
      isCorrect = this.incorrect

    } else { 
      this.userUncorrectAnswer.splice(index, 1);

      if (this.correctAnswers.length === this.userCorrectAnswers.length &&
          this.userUncorrectAnswer.length == 0) {
        isCorrect = this.correct

      } else {
        isCorrect = this.incorrect           
      }
    }
  }

  this.userAnswerXML = this.userCorrectAnswers.join(',')
  this.usersAnswerXMLs  = this.userAnswerXML  + ',' + 
                          this.userUncorrectAnswer.join(',')
  this.usersAnswerXML = this.usersAnswerXMLs.split(',')

  console.log(this.usersAnswerXML)

  if (window.uaXML) {
    this.userAnswerXML = window.uaXML 
    console.log(this.userAnswerXML + "data")   
  }

  // this.usersAnswerXML = window.uaXML
  console.log(window.uaXML)

  this.userAnswerXML  = "<smans type='4'><div id='textID0' userAns='" + 
                         this.usersAnswerXML + "'></div></smans>"

  $("#special_module_user_xml").val(this.userAnswerXML )
  console.log(this.usersAnswerXML)            
}
} // Editor's note: this is an extra curly brace


render() {
  if (this.props.remedStatus) {
    console.log(this.usersAnswerXML)
    console.log("inside remed")
    return (
      <HotspotRemed 
        xml={this.receivedXML}
        userXml={this.usersAnswerXML}
        correctAnswer ={this.ansString}
        type={this.splitType}
      />
    ) 
  } else { 
    return (
      <div className="previewtemplate" style ={template}>
      {this.templateArea(this.state.templateType)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
} // Editor's note: another extra curly brace
} // Editor's note: another one again
```

Comment: Set the `usersAnswerXML` array as a property of state and use `userXml={this.state.usersAnswerXML}` otherwise your component's `userXml` property won't update when you change `this.usersAnswerXML`

Comment: this.usersAnswerXML = this.usersAnswerXMLs.split(',')
            this.setState({
                usersAnswerXML: this.usersAnswerXML
            })

Comment: not working i am doing like this

Comment: Have you changed `userXml` to `userXml={this.state.usersAnswerXML}` as well ?

Comment: yes , i do all ...can i update my code with your solution if you want

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: When are you calling the `handleSplitContentClick` function and inside that function is `this` the same object as the one this `render` function is in ?

Comment: yes same object..... wait i updated my whole code please see my code then give me solution.

Comment: yes now you can see my updated code